# Black-Litterman example

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, reference-request

I'm trying to learn Black-Litterman. I feel like I get the overall idea from books like Risk and Asset Allocation by Meucci as well as some of the early papers which develop the model. What I would really like to see is a simple example worked out in detail by hand. Say a portfolio with 2 or 3 assets. Can anyone provide such an example or perhaps a reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a guide by morningstar: " A step by step guide to the black litterman model" 
https://corporate.morningstar.com/ib/documents/MethodologyDocuments/IBBAssociates/BlackLitterman.pdf

Comment: This link is not valid anymore. I assume you referred to a paper by Thomas M. Idzorek?